# Accessing python classes not imported in __init__

Tags: python, python-import, python-multiprocessing

I'm aiming to patch the python `multiprocessing` library to use their undocumented class ThreadPool instead of Pool.  My current solution is just to

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.Pool = ThreadPool
```

this works fine, but the import statement I have to use to get the `ThreadPool` class is a bit weird, since it's defined in `pool.py` and never imported in `__init__.py`.

Say I had access to the `multiprocessing` module object. How would I access anything in `multiprocessing.pool`? I'm not certain it's possible without using `__file__` and importing the path.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just use `ThreadPool` directly? Or `multiprocessing.dummy`, which is basically "fake multiprocessing with threads"? Or some documented threadpool like [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Sounds like a bad idea to me..

Comment: @user2357112 `multiprocessing.dummy` would work since all it does is use `..pool.ThreadPool` anyway, but the question still remains, how do I access dummy from the module object?

Comment: @MatiasCicero This question is more to figure out if it's possible to do what I want.  I have a Jupyter server running and I'm letting some people run a bit of python code on it.  I just want to patch out some of the multiprocessing stuff so they don't hog the cpu.